Sum of a bounded sequence
In 'Hugh L. Montgomery and Robert C. Vaughan - Multiplicative Number Theory: I. Classical Theory, 2006' the authors stated on pages 155, 156 in (5.45) and (5.46) that a bounded sequence $a_n$ which fullfills
\begin{equation}
   \sum_{n=1}^Na_n(N-n) =\frac{1}{2}N^2 + \mathcal{O}(N^{\frac{3}{2}})
\end{equation}
should fullfill
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^Na_n =N + \mathcal{O}(N^{\frac{3}{4}})\,.
\end{equation}
One should be able to prove this with the methods used to prove Theorem 5.6 on page 150. I have no idea to do that. Maybe someone can give me a hint to carry out this prove.
